# "scanf with printf" vs "fgets with printf"

Tags: c, printf, scanf, fgets

I know about the difference and the advantage/disatvantage of using **scanf** and **fgets**.

I don't understand the relations between printf and this two C standard functions.

I have this simple code:

```
 void print_choice(char * list, char * choice)
{
  /* check parameters */
  if(!list || !choice)
    return;

  printf("list of users: %s\n", list);
  printf("Choice -- ? ");

  /* scanf("%s", &choice); */
  /* fgets(choice, 20, stdin); */

}


int main()
{
  char choice[20];
  char * list = "marco:dario:roberto:franco";

  print_choice(list, choice);
  printf("choice = %s\n", choice);

  return 0;
}
```

if I use `fgets`, *printf* print the result correctly on stdout;

If I use `scanf`, *printf*` doesn't print anything on stdout.

Why this behaviour?

Comment: You need fflush((stdout) after the printf.

Comment: use as _scanf("%s", choice);_ <<- Notice dropped '&'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `scanf("%s", &choice);` which passes a `char **` to `scanf()` when it expects a `char *`.

Drop the `&`.

If your compiler wasn't complaining, you either haven't turned on enough warnings or you need a better compiler.

Comment: Like the part about "If your compiler wasn't complaining".

Comment: Oh sh.. !! Sorry for this stupid mistake!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
scanf("%s", &choice);
```

to

```
scanf("%s", choice);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use

```
scanf("%s", choice);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%s", &choice);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing this  `scanf("%s", &choice);` to this  `scanf("%s", choice);` will cause scanf and fgets to show almost similar behavior.

scanf requires an **address** as an argument. It goes on and stores the input from stdin after converting it based on the supplied format specifier. Here the format specifier is %s so it will try to store the input **at the address pointed by address of choice** . What you need here is the address from where the choice array will begin,which in this case is choice itself.